# Estou tentando copiar um texto para o clipboard via javascript e Jquery e num caso muito especifico não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou escrevendo um Site muito especifico, para atender pessoas com necessidades especiais, o que implica em automatizar quase tudo, apesar do site, ter uma "aparência" comum a qualquer usuário.
Quase a totalidade da navegação, cliques etc, são feitos não só por mouse e teclado, mas por "gestos" e/ou "voz".
Tudo funciona perfeitamente simulando eventos de teclado e mouse via JQuery porem, uma única coisa simplesmente NÃO FUNCIONA. A Copia para Clipboard.
Apesar do Botão receber o evento, a copia não é feita. Mas se clicar fisicamente no botão, funciona perfeitamente.
Alguém saberia explicar o motivo disso e/ou dar uma sugestão de solução?
Já utilizei inúmeras bibliotecas para acessar o Clipboard e com TODAS acontece a mesma coisa.
Segue o codigo que estou usando para testes.

```html
    <!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>trigger/Copy testes</title>
  <style>
  button {
    margin: 10px;
  }
  div {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="primeclick();">

<button>Button #1</button>
<button>Button #2</button>
<div><span>0</span> button #1 clicks.</div>
<div><span>0</span> button #2 clicks.</div>
<!-- Esta é a parte do codigo que interessa -->
<textarea class="textarea">Vamos copiar este texto?</textarea>
<br>
<button class="copiar" >Copiar Texto</button> 
<script>
/*
$( "button:first" ).click(function() {
  update( $( "span:first" ) );
});

$( "button:last" ).click(function() {
  $( "button:first" ).trigger( "click" );
  update( $( "span:last" ) );
});

function update( j ) {
  var n = parseInt( j.text(), 10 );
  j.text( n + 1 );
}
*/
//Copiar
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.copiar');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
    alert('Texto copiado? ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Opa, Não conseguimos copiar o texto, é possivel que o seu navegador não tenha suporte, tente usar Crtl+C.');
  }
});

function primeclick() {
    $( "button:last" ).trigger( "click" );
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está chamando a função

```
<body onLoad="primeclick();">
```

E a função é a seguinte:

```
function primeclick() {
    $( "button:last" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

Como é que o body vai saber qual o botão "last" se não houve o clique?
Sugiro que você sete o botão com um ID.

```
function primeclick() {
    $( "#idButton" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

Comment: O body sabe pois eu referencio o "button:last" e o ultimo botão é justamente ele.
O Problema não é a referencia, quando a pagina carrega, o botão é acionado normalmente mas a resposta da copia é "não".
Ou seja o evento é reconhecido e acionado porem a copia não é feita.

Comment: Fernando, para não passar em branco, eu fiz o que você sugeriu e o resultado foi exatamente o mesmo. Isso reforça o que eu disse antes: "O problema não está no reconhecimento da simulação do click. O problema é que, quando o click é simulado e NÃO FISICO, a copia para o Clipboard não é feita."